# Vue - missing ; after import with local registration

Tags: module, vuejs2

Im getting this error:
[image]

Here is my app.js:

```
require('./bootstrap');

import Vue from 'vue';
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue';
Vue.use(BootstrapVue);


import ScheduleGroupDiscussion from './components/schedule-group-discussion/schedule-group-discussion.component';


const app = new Vue({
    el: '#spoc-gathered',
    components: {
        ScheduleGroupDiscussion,
    }
});
```

and my component:

```
<template>
    <a href="#" class="text-uppercase">{{buttonText}}</a>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'schedule-group-discussion',
        data () {
            return {
                startTime: null,
                buttonText: this.startTime ? 'Edit' : 'Set Time & Date',
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

I Can't seem to find what is wrong here. I can't find an example of app.js with import and local registration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why. but this seems to be PHPStorm auto importing the js classes when you use the component. And it only happened in this one instance.